# I need to replace my tyre on my hybrid - 27.5x1.95 on the current tyre but struggling to find this size Is there a range of sizes that might fit?

Tags: tire, maintenance, replacement

Complete novice here and not sure if the tyre has to be replaced like for like or if there is some wiggle room on the width (1.95) aspect?

Comment: 1.9, 2.0, etc...

Comment: Welcome to the site - I see the question is already closed as a duplicate, because tyre width questions are about the most common questions posted.  Please don't take it personally the question was closed.   If you still have questions after reading the linked question, then consider asking in [chat]